# Does GNOME built-in desktop recorder have no shortcut to stop recording?

Tags: desktop-recording

Currently, I can type <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R</kbd> to start recording with the GNOME built-in desktop recorder, but the same shortcut doesn't stop recording.

Is there any `gsettings` command or other way out that allow me to create a shortcut to make the GNOME built-in desktop recorder stop recording?

Further info:

```
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

The Red Hat documentation of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 with Gnome 40 suggests that the same shortcut with which you started the session could be used to also stop the recording. Alas, this indeed does not work on Ubuntu 22.04.

Probably, it once worked like this, but not anymore. This is, as you rightfully point out, an issue, and it [has been filed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5386) one year ago (as of 2023-12-20).

There might be a way to stop screencasting using a script:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61596274/how-to-start-gnomes-built-in-screen-recorder-via-command-line

https://superuser.com/questions/1367346/how-to-start-gnome-screen-recorder-from-command-line